# How do I submit from values using AJAX in such a way that what is passed to the Servlet is a JSON string?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

So this is my function:

```
function buttonClicked() {
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var field1 = $("#textInput1").val();
    var field2 = $("#textInput2").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"Servvvvlet",
        method: "POST",
        data: { // values from forms in data String

        },
        success: function() {
            // success code
        },
    });
});
```

}

How do I submit the form values in such a way that what is submitted is a JSON string?

Comment: With JSON.stringify? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

By "JSON string", is that a string with JSON in it?

```
function buttonClicked() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        var field1 = $("#textInput1").val();
        var field2 = $("#textInput2").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"Servvvvlet",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}),  // {"foo":"bar"}
            success: function() {
                // success code
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: so in my data I'd put "JSON.stringify({name: field1, email: field2})"
or something similar?

Comment: forgot the content Type . Can't send form encoded data without key/value pair and all you have is value